# Implementing trees in c++

Tags: c++, tree

I want to implement a binary tree where each node contains the `left` and the `right` sub-tree. Here is how my class looks like:

```
class KDTree
{
public:
    KDTree(...);   
    ~KDTree();

private:
    LatLng element; // The value of the node
    KDTree left;    // The left sub-tree
    KDTree right;   // The right sub-tree
};
```

And then my constructor looks like this:

```
KDTree::KDTree(...)
{   
    value = ...;
    if(not_finished)
    {
        left  = KDTree(...);
        right = KDTree(...);
    }
    else
    {
        left = NULL; // how to implement this properly ?
        right= NULL; // how to implement this properly ?
    }
}
```

If I try and put `NULL` as I show above, then the compiler complains that `left` and `right` properties aren't initialized. How can I do this properly ?

Comment: If you have C++11 please consider getting into the habit of using `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. Can you show the exact error you get?

Comment: If every `KDTree` contains two `KDTree`s, then you get infinite recursion, the size is infinite.

Comment: @Shiro you're reinventing a square wheel with this class. Unless it's a homework problem, you should just grab one of the million existing implementations, one that's templated, allocator aware, and exception safe.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus I prefer doing it myself. I don't need it to be templated and I don't think exceptions are that hard to handle. But yes, this is part of my thesis, and I prefer not to use any unnecessary libraries, for no reason. It is much more readable and self-contained this way.

Comment: @Shiro you'd be doing your future self a favor if you research it a bit. IMHO writing data structures is one of the hardest things to do well in c++, and other peoples poorly implemented data structures are one of the biggest headaches professional programmers have to deal with. I say this as someone whose implemented several bad tree data structures in the past and am still dealing with the consequences.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus I agree with you. However, the quality of this data structure and the whole project as a whole will be tested extensively with various data, and so there is no possibility the finished product will be bad.

Comment: How silly. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here. If I were your advisor I'd want you to stop wasting time re-inventing the standard library, use the facilities that everyone else uses in the way that everyone else uses them, and get on with the actual logic of your thesis.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The main purpose of this project is understanding algorithms and data structures. C++ is simply a tool here, not the purpose. But I do see where you are coming from.

Comment: Yeah you really need a reason _not_ to use existing technology, not the other way around. Are you building your own CPU & OS to run this program on, too? :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit KDTrees are not as essential as OS, and they are not part of the standard library.

Comment: Well okay not the standard library but whatever is the _de facto_ industry standard.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fun fact, my usecase of KDTrees is so specific to my project (a routing engine with spatial data) that there are no templated libraries that would help me achieve what I want. This is because I already have an array that gets the `Point` object from the `node_id`. So there is no need to save a reference to the `Point` object on the `KDTree`. Instead, I only save the `node_id`, from which I can retrieve the `Point` object. With this KDTree I can retrieve `node_id` from `Point`. So, the fact that every tree node has only 2 pointers and a `int node_id` saves me tons of ram.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That is at least 25% ram saved  (since my nodes would have 3 properties instead of 4), from whatever any other standard library could offer me. And for this problem, that is HUGE, because there are about 1,5 billion nodes.

Comment: @Shiro: Okay, that's a good reason not to use `std::map`. I think your assertion that there is no existing library in the entire world that already does this fairly basic thing is unrealistic, though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How could someone predict that i already possess another datastructure (an array) therefore my kd-tree can contain less information ? That couldn't possibly work...

Comment: @Shiro: You're underestimating how basic and common this requirement is. The world's a big place! Rule of thumb: whatever you think up, someone already thought it up before. Don't know why you think nobody would have written space-efficient trees before.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Hey, I read up that KD-trees were invented by an undergrad during a lecture, so you never know :)

Comment: @Shiro: That was forty years ago. You think there are no ready-made implementations by now?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh no, I agree with you. I am just generally speaking. You could obviously find a similar tree if you looked at other open source routing engines. Its more fun doing it yourself though. And more educational. I spent 4 days researching the topic. Its really challenging. Coming up with ideas and solutions to problems is a skill that can only be taught by practice.

Comment: @Shiro: That's a good reason :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

left and right should be KDTree pointers like this: KDTree* left, KDTree* right. Then Null will work as used

Also, in the first if statement you might need to change

```
left = KDTree (...);
right = KDTree (...);
```

to

```
left = new KDTree (...);
right = new KDTree (...);
```

Answer (score 1):

The example is incomplete, so I'm just guessing based on what I see.

`KDTree left` and `KDTree right` are objects, not pointers.  So you can't assign `NULL` to them.  Try turning them into pointers:

```
class KDTree
{
    public:
        KDTree(...);   
        ~KDTree();
        // Note: You'll have to clean up your left and right trees in the destructor!

    private:
        LatLng element;   // The value of the node
        KDTree * left;    // The left sub-tree
        KDTree * right;   // The right sub-tree
};


KDTree::KDTree(...)
{   
    value = ...;
    if(not_finished)
    {
        left  = new KDTree(...); // recursive constructor call (nuh-uh! see below)
        right = new KDTree(...); // recursive constructor call (nuh-uh! see below)
    }
    else
    {
        left = NULL; // how to implement this properly ?
        right= NULL; // how to implement this properly ?
    }
}
```

An additional FYI: I see your "recursive constructor call" comment in there.  That's not quite right.  In your original code, `left = KDTree(...);` does *not* recursively call your constructor.  It simply assigns a new `KDTree` to `left` (I'm guessing `KDTree` has an assignment operator).

Comment: I removed "recursive" to not confuse people.

Comment: I shall no longer be confused :)

Comment: Tell me, what is `sizeof(KDTree)` in the original question - pick any platform. Infinite, right?